# How to change the text of an anchor when clicked with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my website. http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html All the code+images+css is there with access to anyone

When anyone clicks on the listen button its background changes into the stop listening and vice versa. This is the functionality I wanted and I got it using jQuery.

What I also want now is the text to change too accordingly. Like, when someone clicks on the "listen" anchor, its text should change to "stop listening", and the same for the stop listening anchor. Like a toggle anchor.

Thanks for the help ! Really appreciate it... :)

Comment: I have posted an answer below using your exact source. Just go to the JSfiddle.

Comment: I checked it out. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the time and effort. Really appreciate it guys ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I made this JSFiddle using your source code.

http://jsfiddle.net/K4Njj/2/

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#container a").click(function(){
        if ($(this).html() == "Stop Listening")
        {
            $(this).html("Listen");
        }
        else if ($(this).html() == "Listen")
        {
            $(this).html("Stop Listening");
        }
    });
});
```

That will simply check to see if the text on the anchor is "Stop Listening" or "Listen" and if it is, it will switch it when you hit the button. It's really the most elegant solution.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I just made one last change (Before it would change any links you put in the link container, now it only affects the listen and stop listening ones)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#first").toggle(function(){
    $(this).text("Stop listening");
}, function(){
    $(this).text("Listen");
});
```

**Online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5AUdJ/

---

**UDPATE**

I see you are using a class to control the listen/stop state. Maybe this will work better.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(".listen")){
        $(this).text("Stop listening").removeClass("listen");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Listen").addClass("listen");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working. Is it because i am using a class of first and not id? I tried that too but didnt work. :(

Comment: I tested on the link you posted and it worked perfectly. The id in the link was "first".

Comment: thank you amosrivera. Just uploaded it on my server and it works. :) Thanks Alot. Just one thing, this new script has malfunctioned my hover state. Check out the website again and the hover state on the last one is perfect(since i didnt add the script to it). But the hover script to the other ones are not functioning correctly. Can you help me out in that. Thanks Alot ! Really appreciate it.. :)

Comment: if you go to http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html and click on the button the text does change as well as the background. :) But the hover state remains the same for both the "listen" and "stop listening" anchors. Check out the source code of the webpage and in the end I have a script that previously changed the hover state by changing the class accordingly for both the anchors. Note how when I dont use your script in the last one "stop listening", it changes the background and hover state but not the text. That is how i want the hover states fora all.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript, you can use the innerHTML property to access and/or change the HTML text of an element.

```
getElementById("first").innerHTML = "newtext"
```